# Is there a Python equivalent to the 'which' command

Tags: python, shell, operating-system

Put another way, is there a cross-platform way of knowing which file will be executed by `subprocess.Popen(file)` without first executing it?

Comment: https://github.com/amoffat/pbs/blob/master/pbs.py#L95

Comment: By default, subprocess inherents the environment of the parent process. So for any executable in the PATH (or the OS in question's equivalent) you don't need to specifiy the location.

Comment: @JoshLee looks like PBS is no longer available.

Comment: https://github.com/amoffat/sh/blob/master/sh.py#L162

Answer (score 10, accepted):

## outdated (not longer true)

I believe there is none in the python libraries

```
>>> def which(pgm):
    path=os.getenv('PATH')
    for p in path.split(os.path.pathsep):
        p=os.path.join(p,pgm)
        if os.path.exists(p) and os.access(p,os.X_OK):
            return p

        
>>> os.which=which
>>> os.which('ls.exe')
'C:\\GNUwin32\\bin\\ls.exe'
```

Answer (score 90):

Python 3.3 added `shutil.which()` to provide a cross-platform means of discovering executables:

http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/shutil.html#shutil.which

> Return the path to an executable which would be run if the given cmd was called. If no cmd would be called, return None.

Sample calls:

```
>>> shutil.which("python")
'/usr/local/bin/python'

>>> shutil.which("python")
'C:\\Python33\\python.EXE'
```

Unfortunately, this has not been backported to 2.7.x.

Comment: Python source for version 3.3's implementation of shutil.which is here (only a few dozen lines): http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/6860263c05b3/Lib/shutil.py#l1068

Comment: if you change line 1110 to `if any([cmd.lower().endswith(ext.lower()) for ext in pathext])` (turn the generator to a list) than it will work in python 2.7.

Comment: Backport available here: https://github.com/mbr/shutilwhich

Comment: shutil.which is also dog slow

Comment: In 2021 this should be the accepted answer.

Comment: @TravisBear, `shutil.which` takes about 100 μs on my machine, so you must have a fast dog! It's slower than a lot of other operations, but you can still do it 10,000 times per second.

Answer (score 15):

An option for Python 2 and 3:

```
from distutils.spawn import find_executable

find_executable('python')  # '/usr/bin/python'

find_executable('does_not_exist')  # None
```

`find_executable(executable, path=None)` simply tries to find 'executable' in the directories listed in 'path'.  Defaults to `os.environ['PATH']` if 'path' is `None`.  Returns the complete path to 'executable' or `None` if not found.

Keep in mind that unlike `which`, `find_executable` does not actually check that the result is marked as executable. You may want to call `os.access(path, os.X_OK)` to check that on your own if you want to be certain that `subprocess.Popen` will be able to execute the file.

---

Also of note, `shutil.which` of Python 3.3+ has been backported and made available for Python 2.6, 2.7, and 3.x via the 3rd-party module [whichcraft](https://github.com/pydanny/whichcraft).

It is available for installation via the aforementioned GitHub page (i.e. `pip install git+https://github.com/pydanny/whichcraft.git`) or the Python package index (i.e. `pip install whichcraft`). It can be used like such:

```
from whichcraft import which

which('wget')  # '/usr/bin/wget'
```

Comment: Avoid distutils because it used deprecated imp which creates a runtime warning.