# How to start Microsoft Edge from Python script using webbrowser

Tags: python, python-webbrowser

Using *webbrowser* lib, I can start both Chrome and Firefox from a python script. It fails for Edge. I noticed ways to start Edge using *webdriver* but my question here is if it is possible to use the following script for edge. It currently starts Chrome only.

```
import webbrowser

chrome_path="C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe"
edge_path="C:\Windows\SystemApps\Microsoft.MicrosoftEdge_8wekyb3d8bbwe\MicrosoftEdge.exe"

webbrowser.register('chrome', None, webbrowser.BackgroundBrowser(chrome_path))
webbrowser.register('edge', None, webbrowser.BackgroundBrowser(edge_path))

webbrowser.get('chrome').open('http://www.google.com')
webbrowser.get('edge').open('http://www.microsoft.com')
```

Comment: I read somewhere that Edge can't be started by running the exe, it is "different".

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Cant speak for your version of Windows, but in the latest, the edge filepath is

C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft\Edge\Application\msedge.exe

Answer (score 2):

import os

os.startfile("msedge")

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This helped me with my problem, thanx. Up until now I was trying subprocess.Popen(["msedge"]) which did not work.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe your path is wrong. Run edge and start task manager. Select edge browser, right click and select 'open file location'(Maybe you can see this name different in task manager bcs I used translate) and then copy the path. set edge_path to this but you should add the file name. For example my edge's exe file's name is 'msedge.exe' dont forget to add this at the and of the path

Answer (score 1):

Your implementation plus [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9877856) answer helped me to open Edge on Linux. Maybe it will help you on Windows also.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of:

```
edge_path="C:\Windows\SystemApps\Microsoft.MicrosoftEdge_8wekyb3d8bbwe\MicrosoftEdge.exe
```

try:

```
edge_path="C:\Windows\SystemApps\Microsoft.MicrosoftEdge_8wekyb3d8bbwe\msedge.exe
```

That's what worked for me atleast
And if not then go to program files, select edge and press the .exe files  properties and copy the path from there.